# CoreData objects or SQL statements for complex reporting?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, core-data

My iOS app has a model carried over from a PostgreSQL database. The application has reporting functionality that has the potential to get more complicated in the future. Also, there may be a need to synchronize local app data with a PostgreSQL database server.

So far I have used CoreData objects to read, write and delete data. I've been translating SQL queries to use CoreData language, but have found it unnecessarily cumbersome for some of them, e.g.:

```
select sum(amount), date from db.table group by date;
```

This is just one example and the application will potentially require more complex reporting queries in the future. Because of that I am thinking of switching from CoreData to querying SQLite directly (I could use queries already written to query the PostgreSQL DB).

My questions are:

- Would it be worth it to keep using CoreData instead of SQL queries, considering that reporting is a core feature of the application (i.e. will require non-trivial SELECT queries)?
- Would it be feasible to use both SQL (for complex SELECT queries) and CoreData (for the rest of the application) with the same storage?

Answer (score 1):

I would move over to CoreData it's way fast and really simple, once you get the syntax down. The big difference is you replace sql statements with stuff like this:

```
 // Retrieve the entity from the local store -- much like a table in a database
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"AppSettings" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:entity];


// Set the predicate -- much like a WHERE statement in a SQL database
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"version == %@", @"Default"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];


// Set the sorting -- mandatory, even if you're fetching a single record/object

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"version" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];
[request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
sortDescriptors = nil;
sortDescriptor = nil;

// Request the data -- NOTE, this assumes only one match, that 
// yourIdentifyingQualifier is unique. It just grabs the first object in the array. 
AppSettings *appSettings1 =[[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] objectAtIndex:0];

request = nil;


//Update the object
appSettings1.backGroundImage = [NSNumber numberWithInt: backGroundGraphics.selectedSegmentIndex];
```

Hope this helps there are also tool in the MAC app store under the developer section that Really help Core Data Editor is one  use all the time.

You can always use SQL directly but the data store structure looks a bit funny with the Core Data fields.

Comment: Core Data Editor, I have to check that out!

Comment: I'm already acquainted with the stuff you mention. CoreData works well in those simple cases, my particular problem is with the equivalent of GROUP BY in CoreData and complex SELECT queries.

Thanks for pointing me to Core Data Editor.

Answer (score 1):

I dropped core data for the same reason, I have some pretty complex queries and it was too much of a pain in the butt to translate for use by core data. Just stick with pure SQLLite and writing the SQL out manually is the way to go in my opinion. Alternatively, you can use FMDB as a wrapper for SQLlite https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb

Comment: I will definitely check FMDB out. Have you tried using both SQL and CoreData methods to query the same model?

Comment: Nope, I haven't tried using them both at the same time, that would be even more of a pain IMO. Besides wasn't it so nice and easy writing this out the first time "select sum(amount), date from db.table group by date" :)